# SailAlign Sofware Installation Speech Processing

Tags: perl, audio

Ambiguous call resolved as CORE::read(), qualify as such or use & at (eval 23) line 4.
Subroutine Audio::Wav::Read::read redefined at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Audio/Wav/Read.pm line 316.
[FATAL] (/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/SailTools/SailHtkWrapper.pm line 414) HVite failed:  ERROR [+6510]  LOpen: Unable to open label file support/test/local/asr/timit_5.0-11000.rec

Answer (score 0):

The installation procedure for [`SailAlign`](http://cvsp.cs.ntua.gr/~nassos/sail_align.html) is listed on its `github page`.  Follow that in detail.

If you continue to have problems, edit this question to list

- Which steps worked?
- Where did the error occur?
- What are the specs of your environment.